# Checking if a codeword in a cyclic code generates it

Tags: polynomials, coding-theory

Let's have $g(x)$ be the generator polynomial of a cyclic code $C=<g(x)>$. For any $h(x)\in C$, what would be the condition so that $<h(x)> = <g(x)>$ - meaning h(x) generates the code (albeit not necessarily being THE generator polynimial)?

Comment: The generator $g(x)$ of a cyclic code is usually selected to be a factor of $x^n-1$. As $h(x)$ and $\gcd(h(x),x^n-1)$ generate the same cyclic code, this gives you the test: check whether $g(x)=\gcd(h(x),x^n-1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ to generate the same ideal of $\mathbb{F}[x]/(x^n -1)$.  You automatically have $\langle h(x) \rangle \subseteq \langle g(x) \rangle$.  You need to have $g(x)$ be a multiple of $h(x)$ in order to guarantee equality.  As $h(x)$ is already a multiple of $g(x)$, this means you need to have $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ differ by a unit of $\mathbb{F}[x]/(x^n -1)$.

For example, in $\mathbb{F}_{3}[x]/(x^3 -1)$, consider the code generated by $g(x) = x+1$.  Then the polynomial $h(x) = -x^{2} -1 = (-x^2)(x+1)$, and $-x^{2}$ is a unit (since $(-x^{2})(-x)$$ = x^{3} = (x^{3}-1)+1 = 1$). Therefore $h(x)$ will also generate the code.

Comment: What is a unit of [x]/(xn−1)? How can I calculate [x]/(xn−1)'s units?

Comment: A unit of $R=\mathbb{F}[x]/(x^{n}-1)$ is an element that has an inverse. Note that even though $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, $R$ is a ring and so not every element has an inverse.  Elements of the form $ax^{k}$, where $a \in \mathbb{F}$ ($a \neq 0$) and $0 \leq k < n$ are units.  There are others; any polynomial that has no common factors with $x^{n}-1$ is also a unit.  I can't give an easy way to find all of these, however (though this does provide a way to check if an element is a unit; many algebra packages provide a way to check the GCD of two polynomials).